# Telegram Bot Random Images (How to send random images with Telegram-Bot)

Tags: random, telegram, telegram-bot

```
const TeleBot = require('telebot');


const bot = new TeleBot({
token: 'i9NhrhCQGq7rxaA' // Telegram Bot API token.
});

bot.on(/^([Hh]ey|[Hh]oi|[Hh]a*i)$/, function (msg) {
return bot.sendMessage(msg.from.id, "Hello Commander");
});

var Historiepics = ['Schoolfotos/grr.jpg', 'Schoolfotos/boe.jpg', 
'Schoolfotos/tobinsexy.jpg'];


console.log('Historiepics')
console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * Historiepics.length));
var foto = Historiepics[(Math.floor(Math.random() * Historiepics.length))];

bot.on(/aap/, (msg) => {
return bot.sendPhoto(msg.from.id, foto);
});



bot.start();
```

The result I'm getting from this is just one picture everytime, but if I ask for another random picture it keeps showing me the same one without change.

Answer (score 0):

I recently figured this out, so I'll drop an answer for anyone that runs into this issue.

The problem is with Telegram's cache. They cache images server side so that they don't have to do multiple requests to the same url. This protects them from potentially getting blacklisted for too many requests, and makes things snappier.

Unfortunately if you're using an API like [The Cat API](https://thecatapi.com) this means you will be sending the same image over and over again. The simplest solution is just to somehow make the link a little different every time. This is most easily accomplished by including the current epoch time as a part of the url.

For your example with javascript this can be accomplished with the following modifications

```
bot.on(/aap/, (msg) => {
  let epoch = (new Date).getTime();
  return bot.sendPhoto(msg.from.id, foto + "?time=" + epoch);
});
```

Or something similar. The main point is, as long as the URL is different you won't receive a cached result. The other option is to download the file and then send it locally. This is what Telebot does if you pass the `serverDownload` option into `sendPhoto`.